# organizing google maps javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am about to re-write a project I created last year. One of the main parts is to re-write the front end, which is basically all google maps javascript api.

One of the main problems with the project is that the javascript is rather disorganized and hard to maintain.

I was wondering if there are any javascript tools/frameworks that will help me with organizing my js code.

I have looked into backbone, but I am not sure how I can integrate it with the google maps api.

Are there any other frameworks I should take into consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone is by far on the the fastest growing MVC frameworks for JavaScript, and it's used by quite a few well-known projects. The advantage of using the most widely used tools of course is that they're more likely to continue to be supported by the community, not just in development, but in the number of bugs reported and fixed.

With that said, you may find [more information on different JavaScript frameworks in this review article.](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/).

Finally, an API is really just a simplified abstraction on top of layers of more complex logic. There really shouldn't be any reason why this API shouldn't work with Google Maps API as it's all JavaScript under the hood.